# Foot muscle weakness related to overpronation

Tags: strength, injury, barefoot

I've come to the conclusion that an excessive overpronation partly is a problem related to the weakness of the foot muscles and in particular:

- Intrinsic foot muscles (abductor hallucis, flexor digitorum brevis etc.)
- Weak posterior tibialis
- Weak anterior tibialis
- Weak peroneus longus
- Weak extrinsic foot muscles (flexor hallucis longus, flexor digitorum longus)

Now I need some guidance with exercises that strengthens these muscles. So far my plan is to:

- Transition to minimalist shoes for everyday wear(already made but haven't run in them yet)
- Various balance plate exercises

Balancing, throw a ball to a wall, squats, etc.

- Short foot exercises(But right now these are VERY hard to do(unable to))
  Links:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6izsrcUZ0k
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n01CTSYfowA(this is easier)
- Calf raises

**Is this enough to tackle all of the muscles mentioned above or do I need additional exercises/techniques?**

Comment: Can you elaborate on the plate exercises and short foot exercises you're planning to do?

Comment: Of course! I'll edit my post.

Comment: In addition to the foot muscles, have you already concluded that your lower extremity ranges and strength are normal?  Often an over-pronation of the foot may be a result of reduced mobility or weakness somewhere else up the chain.  The excessive pronation can be a compensation, not the actual problem.

Comment: They are not normal. I do have tight muscles and they need to be stretched. But since I don't know the to what degree every joint contribute I attacked all of them throughout the kinetic chain. This includes anterior pelvic tilt, internal rotation of the hip/tibia, adduction of the hip and pronation of the ankle and foot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although weakness or limited mobility anywhere in the kinetic chain may lead to excessive pronation as a compensation, limited ankle dorsi-flexion is often a prime culprit.

To test your **dorsi-flexion range** you can see if you can fully squat without lifting your heels or losing your balance. Or another quick [lunge test](http://www.somastruct.com/ankle-stiffness-and-its-relationship-to-flat-feet-and-overpronation/) uses a ruler and the wall.
If you find limitation in ankle dorsi-flexion, here are some good exercises to [stretch your muscles and mobilize the joint](http://www.somastruct.com/increasing-ankle-dorsiflexion-mobility/).

Your short foot exercise video you linked to is good, as is [towel pleating](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEqqyyCRHbA) which will help you target toe flexors. (Sorry for the long winded video.)

To specifically target your requested muscles you can use resistance bands:

- The **anterior tibialis** dorsi-flexes and inverts (pulls the foot up and in).  [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffpStkCs4ZQ) shows how to isolate it with rubber tubing or resistance band or with standing at the wall for support.
- The **posterior tibialis** also inverts the foot (turns it in) but it plantar flexes rather than dorsi-flexion, so you would use the band to resist pointing the foot down and in.
- The **peroneus longus** and brevis evert (turn the foot out) and the longus helps to plantar flex (point the foot down).  [Rubber tubing or theraband](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-1YS7kis3s) linked around the feet while you point and push your feet out against the resistance of the band will strengthen these muscles.

This [quick video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9o9BVLlQrQ) shows dorsi-flexion, plantar-flexion, eversion and inversion with a resistance band.